# Formating text in react-bootstrap Card.Text

Tags: formatting, react-bootstrap, styling

I can't seem to workout how to format text within a react-bootstrap Card.  I've tried many different things and read many articles all of which don't work.

The problem is that the text I put into my Card.text element is centred.  I want to justify or left justify it.  Here's a code snippet that is centred....

```
<Card.Text>
This is some sample text.  It appears centred which seems to be the default style.
</Card.Text>
```

It seems that I can apply a class using the boostrap css.  I've used the 'lead' class and it does indeed apply the style as expected.

```
<Card.Text class='lead'>
This is some sample text.  It still appears centred and applies the lead style as expected.
</Card.Text>
```

When I use the text-justify class it has no effect whatsoever

```
<Card.Text class='text-justify'>
This is some sample text.  It still appears centred and applies the lead style as expected.
</Card.Text>
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something here.  There are no useful instructions on the react-bootstrap docs site.  If somebody could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<Card.Text className="text-start">Nunc malesuada eget est fringilla dapibus.</Card.Text>`

This should align text to left (`text-center` - in center, and `text-end` - to the right).

Use `className` in React instead of `class`.